# How to implement mongoose primary key factory?

Tags: mongoose

I was looking into `mongoose.createConnection` options and noticed the `pkFactory`field, which documentation says: `Custom primary key factory to generate _id values (see Custom primary keys).`. The problem is that I can't find much documentation about this option, what it means and how to implement this (infact I found nothing). So can someone please tell me what this option is and where can I find some docs about it? :)

Comment: Could you provide the link please?

Comment: If I had the link than I won't make this question  Anyway you can see the option [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/MongoClient.html) but aside that piece of doc I wrote in the question there seems to be nothing more...

Comment: Since you are talking about mongoose, I went to the mongoose documentation and didn't find anything related to `pkFactory`. That's why I asked for related link.

Comment: Yes, this is strange. There's no mention of this option in the standard documentation, but there is in the github.io one